# In lightning yet UserInfo.getUiThemeDisplayed returns 'Theme3'

Tags: lightning

I hgave a standard new button that is overriden by a VF page, in that page's controller I am using:

```
    `System.debug(UserInfo.getUiThemeDisplayed());
    if(UserInfo.getUiThemeDisplayed().equals('Theme4d')){
        System.debug('Navigate to lightning component!');
     }`
```

to redirect to a lightning component if the user clicks this New Button(Overriden by VF) in lightning. It's not working. [HERE](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_userinfo.htm) it says that the name for lightning theme is **Theme4d**. But my debug yeilds **Theme3**?

[image]

The New Button is clicked here in the drop down. What's the problem here ?

Comment: Hard to say without more info (I don't see a "New" button that could be being overridden, for instance). But if the VF page is being called when the button is clicked, and `UserInfo.getUiThemeDisplayed()` is being called, say, in the controller's constructor,  and the VF isn't Lightning-styled, then it makes sense to me that at that moment, the value is Theme3 (Classic), even if nothing has been rendered on screen yet. Maybe `UserInfo.getUiTheme()`, which shows the configured preference, would work better here.

Comment: This problem eventually went away, I created a test page and it started giving the right value, not sure what I did to fix it.